# Unable to parse JSON that contains upper case key in Groovy

Tags: json, rest, groovy, escaping

I'm attempting to parse JSON from a REST API and am unable to access the data when the  key to that data is in uppercase format.

```
{
    "body": {
        "devices": [{
            "_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "cipher_id": "xxxxxxxx",
            "last_status_store": 1502808369,
            "modules": [{
                "_id": "xxxxxxx",
                "type": "xxxxxxx",
                "last_message": 1502808365,
                "last_seen": 1502808359,
                "dashboard_data": {
                    "time_utc": 1502808359,
                    "Temperature": 18.9,
                    "temp_trend": "down",
                    "Humidity": 27,
                    "date_max_temp": 1502804720,
                    "date_min_temp": 1502808359,
                    "min_temp": 18.9,
                    "max_temp": 22.2
                },
                "data_type": [
                    "Temperature",
                    "Humidity"
                ],
                "last_setup": 1502731328,
                "battery_vp": 6354,
                "battery_percent": 100,
                "rf_status": 67,
                "firmware": 44
            }],
            "place": {
                "altitude": 63.395306309052,
                "city": "xxxxxx",
                "country": "US",
                "timezone": "America/New_York",
                "location": [-72.532673,
                    42.0425917
                ]
            },
            "station_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "type": "NAMain",
            "dashboard_data": {
                "AbsolutePressure": 1004.6,
                "time_utc": 1502808354,
                "Noise": 50,
                "Temperature": 22.7,
                "temp_trend": "up",
                "Humidity": 69,
                "Pressure": 1012.1,
                "pressure_trend": "stable",
                "CO2": 0,
                "date_max_temp": 1502808290,
                "date_min_temp": 1502801263,
                "min_temp": 21.3,
                "max_temp": 22.7
            },
            "data_type": [
                "Temperature",
                "CO2",
                "Humidity",
                "Noise",
                "Pressure"
            ],
            "co2_calibrating": false,
            "date_setup": 1502731277,
            "last_setup": 1502731277,
            "module_name": "Indoor",
            "firmware": 132,
            "last_upgrade": 1502731279,
            "wifi_status": 51
        }]
    },
    "status": "ok",
    "time_exec": 0.019752025604248,
    "time_server": 1502808443
}
```

I am trying to access the JSON using a Groovy Json slurper and executing the following command. The response comes back fine in my debugger.Reponse.content is value of the HTTPrequest that i sent to the server.

```
def stationInfo = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.content as String)
def outsideTemp = stationInfo.body.devices.modules.dashboard_data.Temperture    
def outsideHumidty = stationInfo.body.devices.modules.dashboard_data.Humidty    
def insideTemp = stationInfo.body.devices.dashboard_data.Temperture
```

outsideTemp,outsideHumidty, and insideTemp are all eqaull to "[null]" when i view them in my debugger. Any ideas on why this is happening, and how to fix it? Is the compiler assuming something because these are uppercase?

Comment: Are we to assume that the other elements in dashboard_data are returned correctly?  (if so could you state that explicitly in your question, please.)

Comment: Probably the issue is in that `devices` is an array and should be accessed by `[index]`, whereas you treat is as plain object

Comment: Ditto for `"modules"`

Comment: Everything is returned correctly in the json, and I have no prob accessing other fields by referencing them in this way(plain object)

Comment: Another thing to note is that these uppercase values are syntax highlighted when I reference them but if left lower case they are not

Comment: @Maz, Are you using it in SoapUI's Script Assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks are you almost there.

Note that, the json you have attached does not seem to be valid, fixed to be able to work.

```
def pJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response.content as String)
println pJson.body.devices.modules.dashboard_data.Temperature.flatten()
println pJson.body.devices.dashboard_data.Temperature.flatten()
```

Similar to `Temparature`, you can get it work for `Humidity` as well.

You can see the same in the <kbd>[demo](http://ideone.com/iNQtXe)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you a ton. I also misspelt temperature and humidity which didn't help.